# Is there a custom sorting function in material-table to sort file sizes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dashboard, material-table

I'm using material-table (mbrn/material-table) to develop a dashboard and I have column contains memory values with Megabyte (MB) and Gigabyte (GB).
Normal sort option does not work as expected because of the different file sizes.
Is there a custom sorting function in material-table to sort file sizes (MB & GB) ?

https://github.com/mbrn/material-table.git

above github repo I used to develop the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but you could write a custom logic to create your own filter in just a few seconds.

```
// your logic
const sortBySize() = (row, value) => {
     console.log('row', row, 'value', value);
} 

const columns = [
    { title: "File name", field: "fileName" },
    { title: "size", field: "size", customSort: sortBySize() }
];
```

Useful link: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/sorting (Custom Sorting Algorithm Example)

Comment: in the explain in material table docs, `customSort: (a, b) => a.name.length - b.name.length` this is the example for custom sort. can u please tell me how to console.log `a` and `b` here. I tried every way I could think of to console log those two but couldn't

Comment: what did you console? can you add your code?

Comment: `customSort: (a, b) => console.log('a.name :',  a.name, 'b.name :', b.name)` I did something like this

Comment: @ShakyaKarunathilake just click on the column sort icon(arrow icon next to the column title) and you should see the console log values